# whats the delegated or "on load" version for loaded AND dynamicly added content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

how can i rewrite all of my script or better in what scheme to have them running even for dynamic added content?

example theese here:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  disable_search_threshold: 10,
  width: "100%"
});

$('.fdatepicker').fdatepicker({
    language: 'de',
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    weekStart:1
});
```

if i change it to

```
jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen({
    ...
});
```

it's only working with the already loaded content, but not working on dynamicly added contents. would be nice if this would work :D

```
$(document).(".chosen-select").chosen({
    ...
});
```

pls help. gonna load a lot of stuff via ajax in modals, divs, ... there must be a way to unify this?!

Comment: The concept of delegation for dynamic elements really applies more to event handling, not for running a particular plugin against a set of elements that don't exist yet. Run the plugin immediately after adding the elements.

Comment: ok.. and is there a way to tell jquery to check the full / loaded content again pls? so the plugins will run in a ajax modal too? or after replacing the content of a div with a new select field or a date field?

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle plugin initialization for dynamic elements like how you do event delegation.

For handling events from dynamically created elements you can use event delegation.

But for plugin initialization, you need to call the plugins after the elements are created.

So

```
function initialize($el){

    $(".chosen-select", $el).chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 10,
      width: "100%"
    });

    $('.fdatepicker', $el).fdatepicker({
        language: 'de',
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
        weekStart:1
    });

}
```

then

```
$(initialize);// to handle already present elements
```

then after the dynamic elemnets are loaded call the `initialize` method again like

```
$(el).html(content);
initialize($(el));
```

Comment: thanks, understand what you maen. but this means if i open / close a modal with dynamic content, and open/close, open/close,... i will get a lot of event listeners for the different classes i genereated. each time $el has to be different (like $el = ".classname"+timestamp) - else the plugins will fire multiple times.
isn't there another way, to keep jquery listening or better all plugins without reinit everything or parts?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Chosen documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events):

> #### Updating Chosen Dynamically
>
> If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen
>   to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "chosen:updated"
>   event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated
>   content.
>
> ```
> $("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
> ```

After you load your dynamic content, call the above to trigger Chosen to pick up the changes.

Note that you still have to call `$(...).chosen` on the elements; the above is just to update when the list of options changes.

Below is a sample of adding a new `<select>` and changing the options in an existing one.

```js
$(function() {
  // Register the first select
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
    
  setTimeout(function() {
    // New select added
    $('<select id="second" class="chosen-select">' +
         '<option value="Second">Second</option>' +
      '</select>')
      .appendTo('body')
      .chosen();
      
    // Existing select updated
    $("#first")
      .empty()
      .append($("<option/>").val("Changed").text("Changed"))
      .append($("<option/>").val("Another").text("Another"))
      .trigger("chosen:updated");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select id="first" class="chosen-select">
  <option value="First">First</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks tavnab: but it's more about getting a code where every plugins runs, no matter hoch much content i add/append to a loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on() (1.7+, or .delegate()) to bind event listeners to dynamically added content.

```
    $(document).on('eventName', '.chosen-select', function(){
```

Another option you have is to use the `pageLoad()` function instead of `$(document).ready()` to bind your event listeners.

`pageLoad` is called even after an async request returns such with AJAX calls.